# How to dynamically create views for list adapter with each item of the list view having another set of list items?

Tags: android

I have adapter for a list view that display a list of questions. Each question has answer options with either a check box or radio button and optionally with image along with answer option. The number of answer options varies on the type of question, for example 1 question may have 2 radio button answer options and some other question may have 4 check box answer options along with image view. A question cannot have both check box and radio button as answer option at one time.

How to implement such requirements? Do I need to have nested adapter one for the question and another adapter inside a question? I am able to achieve my question answer by dynamically and programmatically creating the views inside getView() of adapter. But the fact is that I am not able to reuse a created view of the answer option for each answer option. It always creates the answer views for each option that takes so much time to render and display data to the user.

How to optimize my solution if I am on the right way?
Thank you.

### Some Code Snippets is shown below:

1. Inside getView() method:

//optionsList contains answer option for each question. So I loop it to create the each view.

```
for (int opt = 0; opt < optionsList.size(); opt++) {
    addOptionsView(opt, optionsList.get(opt), position);
}
//The above for loop will be for each question
```

2. Inside addOptionsView() method:

(In one row, i have two horizontal linear layout one for answer image and answer text and second one for CheckBox or RadioButton):

```
//Each answer option
final LinearLayout optionRow = new LinearLayout(getContext());//Parent

//For image or answer text
final LinearLayout imageOrText = new LinearLayout(getContext());//Child1

//For radio or checkbox
final LinearLayout radioOrCheckbox = new LinearLayout(getContext());//Child2

//add image when option has an image
if (mData.get(questionNo).getOptionImages().size() > 0) {
//create ImageView here
    imageOrText.addView(optionImage);
}
TextView mOptionName = new TextView(getContext());
mOptionName.setText(optionName);//Here create answer option and set the text on it.
imageOrText.addView(mOptionName);
optionRow.addView(imageOrText);

radioOrCheckbox.addView(optionCheckType);//Check type is either CheckBox or RadioButton
optionRow.addView(radioOrCheckbox); // Finally add above two layout in parent view.

//something more like this
viewHolder.txtQuestion.setText(mData.get(position).getQuestion());
//Here view holder class
private class ViewHolder {

TextView txtQuestion;
LinearLayout llQuestionLayout;

public ViewHolder(View view) {
    txtQuestion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.questionValue);
    llQuestionLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.questionLayout);
    }
}
```

Note:
   Reuse code for each answer option view is not happening in the above code snippet, So it takes time to render data as it creates the answer view for each answer option dynamically.

Comment: I would recommend you try to get some code down first. Don't be afraid to show what you have. It's better than people trying to guess what you already have down and you have a better chance of getting more responses.

Comment: I will upload the code sure. Thanks.

Comment: You need a ListAdapter for your ListView. That adapter will create views for the items in the list. Those views can be "anything". If that view contains or is a ListView then that ListView will need a corresponding ListAdapter.

Comment: So this means that i can have another ListView(Answer) inside the parent ListView(Questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recyclerview for both of your lists. Create two adapters one for each of your recyclerviews. Individual recycler views will handle the reusability of views. 
I found a article which may be handy for you to get the concept 
https://dannysu.com/2015/10/11/list-in-list-in-list/. Nesting recycler views is the better way to avoid memory use on ui layer, as it handles creation of views.